# What does `!((n % 5 != 0) || (n % 20 == 0))` trasnform into? and why? I don't seem to get it

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators, modulo

Title. I need to know what `!((n % 5 != 0) || (n % 20 == 0))` transforms into and why. I say transforms because it has the `!` in the beginning.

I tried transforming it to `((n%5==0) || (n%20==0))` but I am pretty sure this is not the right answer.

Thanks!!

Comment: Look up deMorgan's laws. It should be `((n%5==0) && (n%20!=0))`

Comment: This feels like an assignment... Does it help if I point you to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra)?

Answer (score 2):

Negation is harder than it looks.

"A or B" is true if at least one of A and B is true.

Thus its negation, "not (A or B)", must be true if neither A nor B is true, which is the same as both A and B being false.

That is, the negation is equivalent to "(not A) and (not B)".

And that leads you to `!(n % 5 != 0) && !(n % 20 == 0)`, or `(n % 5 == 0) && (n % 20 != 0)`.

This is one of DeMorgan's laws, which you can memorise, but they are not diffult to "discover" for yourself, and you just need to remember to "invert" the operation as well as the operands.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to use [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra), you can distribute the NOT into the expressions by NOT'ing each expression and flipping OR's to AND's (and vice versa).

So

```
!((n % 5 != 0) || (n % 20 == 0))
```

Can become

```
(!(n % 5 != 0) && !(n % 20 == 0))
```

Which can become

```
((n % 5 == 0) && (n % 20 != 0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! so it becomes `(!(n % 5 != 0) && !(n % 20 == 0))` because the `!` is outside the paranthesis right?
I mean if it was `(!(n % 5 != 0) || (n % 20 == 0))`
it would've been 




`((n%5==0) || (n%20==0))` 



right?

Comment: That looks correct, yea @jake. But since the NOT is all the way outside the parens, you have to distribute it to everything.

Comment: i know i'm not supposed to comment thanks. but thanks. a lot

Comment: I have one more small question. I figured the calculus ones, but I can't figure out the equal, less, greater. `!((u > t) || (t > u))` 

in this one for example, I switched it to 

`((u<t) && (t<u)`

which I don't think it's correct. I think I should've used less or equal? I am not sure.

Comment: The opposite of `a > b` will be `a <= b`, that's what you're missing here @jake ;)

Comment: thanks!! so only if it's greater? what if it was `!(a<b)` would it have been `(a>=b)` ? @scohe001

Comment: Exactly @Jake. Since `a < b` would evaluate false in every case where `a >= b`.

Answer (score 1):

Original: `!((n % 5 != 0) || (n % 20 == 0))`

Applying De Morgan's laws: `(!(n % 5 != 0) && !(n % 20 == 0))`

Making it clearer (assuming `n` is something like `int` and operators are not overloaded):
 `((n % 5 == 0) && (n % 20 != 0))`

Now you have the result.